# why highlighting keywords of C/C++ is not activated with command prompt

Tags: notepad++

It seems weird that if I create a source file (i.e. `.cpp .h .c`) via the command prompt, the keywords are not highlighted with different colors. When I close the source file and reopen it, the highlighting feature back to normal.

In command prompt, I do

`start notepad++ main.cpp`

First the notepad++ asks me that this file doesn't exist, Create it? If I hit yes, then this is the first look

[image]

When I close it and reopen it, it looks as follows

[image]

I know it is not big deal but I'm curious why this occurs and if there is a such solution.

Comment: Seems working fine on my machine though.

Comment: @YuHao, which notepad++ and version of Windows you are using?

Comment: Notepad++ 6.5.5 on Windows7.